# Can I define a custom URL scheme for iOS in Phonegap Build?

Tags: ios, cordova, url-scheme, phonegap-build

I do know that I can implement custom URL scheme for my Apps editing my `plist.info` in xCode like **[this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Custom%20URL%20Scheme%20Handling.md)**, but I was wondering if this can also be done with an App built with Phonegap Build. The **[docs](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml)** do not state anything.

I am fearing that this is actually not possible, but since I did not find anything at all on this topic on the web I thought it might be worth giving it a try here, even if it's just for creating a reference that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is built into PhoneGap at least as far back as version 2.2.0 (Oct 31, 2012) so it should work if you use PG Build and just update your plist file.  Here is some sample XML that works for me:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.cams.myapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myApp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

You should use the Property editor to edit this file and get the format correct.

[image]

Comment: But how would I edit the plist file when all I can use to configurate my build process is the `config.xml`? Would I need to hack/unpack the `.ipa`?

Comment: How do you access the parameters from javascript?